# "Could not convert string to DateTimeOffset:" in ASP.NET webservice call, any idea what format the string is in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, date-format

I'm using a web service that I'm pretty sure is ASP.NET with an SQL Server backend.

I'm able to make webservice calls to it and have them return, but I just tried to use one and I got back the following error message:

```
{
    "Data": "Could not convert string to DateTimeOffset: 2019-08-02T013:00:00+00:00. Path 'StartTime', line 1, position 41.",
    "Status": "error",
    "ErrorCodes": [],
    "validationRules": {}
}
```

The format I'm sending appears to be:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTZHH:MM:SS+XX:XX
```

Where I'm uncertain what `XX:XX` really is in the format.

Can someone identify the format?  It looks to me like an ISO format.  I'm reading the documentation for the webservice and sort of using an example for it, of course I had to change the date to support data that's in our database so it actually returns something.

If it helps at all the webservice is reporting the following version of ASP.NET

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Length: 148125
< Content-Type: application/json
< Expires: -1
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: What kind of web service is it? You need to show your code and provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @mason It's internal to where I work, so I don't think that would do you much good.  I'm using `curl` to pull it.  I'm certain it's the `StartTime` argument because I've made other date-stampless calls to the same webservice and gotten a reply.

Comment: The documentation says it's a `.NET (C#) Type` of `DateTimeOffset` and that the type expected is `Date and time with offset` for that argument.

Comment: Yes, it does matter what type of web app it is. The serialization library it uses may have specific ways of converting types.

Comment: Looks like it could be because of the timezone: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1237

Comment: @mason Is what I added above the information you are looking for the "kind" of webservice it is?  Or do you need something else?

Comment: That simply tells us it's ASP.NET. But that's a large umbrella. What I'm specifically interested in is the JSON deserialization library being used.